# How to get post ID from button and pass title to Modal

Tags: php, loop

```
    <div><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($image_upload,$size = 'full');?><br/>
      <span class="name"><?php echo $title ?></span><span class="jobtitle"><?php echo $jobtitle ?></span>
      <a onclick="return moreinfoModal(this);" id="<?php get_the_ID();?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moreinfo-modal" href="javascript:void(0);" class="info">more info</a>
    </div>


    <div id="moreinfo-modal" role="dialog">
          <div class="teammember_div">
            <a id="close-moreinfo" onclick='return closeMoreInfoModal();' href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="https://brentbrookbush.com/wp-content/themes/brent/images/svgs/icon.svg"></a>
            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($image_upload,$size = 'full');?>
            <p><?php echo $title ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $about ?></p>
            <span class="jobtitle"><?php echo $jobtitle ?></span>

            <span id="moreinfo" style="display: inherit;"></span>
            <a id="modal-join" class="btn-cta" href="/sign-up/">Become a Member!</a>
          </div>
        </div>

    <?php }?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I am am displaying 4 cards with names and job titles and a button to open a modal. Once the user clicks on the button it opens a modal with a image, title, about bit etc...

Sadly, I can only get it to open a Modal with the details of one post. I'd like to match to modal content with the content of the cards, if that makes sense.

So
card = Harry
Modal = Harry

```
<script> function moreinfoModal(field) {
        console.log(field.id);
        $('#moreinfo-modal').toggleClass('open');
    }


    function closeMoreInfoModal() {
        $('#moreinfo-modal').toggleClass('open');
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.close-pill', function(e) {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    </script>
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: It seems you don't have a part that insert data into modal popup in js part

Comment: yeah and that's where I am a bit at a loss. Would appreciate a bit of guidance. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we display post data in model with on click of button we have to provide the post-id with data attribute in for specific model target.

Please add post-id in data-target in anchor tag as well as in main div tag ID.

I have modified your code here:

```
<div><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($image_upload,$size = 'full');?><br/>
  <span class="name"><?php echo $title; ?></span><span class="jobtitle"><?php echo $jobtitle; ?></span>
  <a onclick="return moreinfoModal(this);" id="<?php echo get_the_ID();?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moreinfo-modal-<?php echo get_the_ID();?>" href="javascript:void(0);" class="info">more info</a>
</div>


<div id="moreinfo-modal-<?php echo get_the_ID();?>" class= "moreinfo-modal" role="dialog">
      <div class="teammember_div">
        <a id="close-moreinfo" onclick='return closeMoreInfoModal();' href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="https://brentbrookbush.com/wp-content/themes/brent/images/svgs/icon.svg"></a>
        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($image_upload,$size = 'full');?>
        <p><?php echo $title ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $about ?></p>
        <span class="jobtitle"><?php echo $jobtitle ?></span>

        <span id="moreinfo" style="display: inherit;"></span>
        <a id="modal-join" class="btn-cta" href="/sign-up/">Become a Member!</a>
      </div>
    </div>

<?php }?>
</div>
</div>
```

As well as you can change js code with click on class instead of div ID attribut like:

```
<script> function moreinfoModal(field) {
        console.log(field.id);
        $('.moreinfo-modal').toggleClass('open');
    }


    function closeMoreInfoModal() {
        $('.moreinfo-modal').toggleClass('open');
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.close-pill', function(e) {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    </script>
```

Hope this can solved your problem. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code - it's not currently working as it stands, but it moved me into the right direction so I'll keep working on it. Thanks!

Comment: so whilst it's listing the modals, its listing all modals on one click - so its listing all post IDs and not just one. Any advice?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what is the actual problem you have faced with the code and why all modal can be listed on one click button. Can you please share full page code so i can understand where you wrong? Thanks!

Comment: No worries, got it fixed so it only calls one modal - thanks!

Comment: That's great... :)